# JIRA User Lookup By Email

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Is there a way to lookup a JIRA user by email (using the REST API Call)? I can't seem to find a function call that covers this ability. I am using JIRA 7.1.2 and need to make a rest call to JIRA to list out email ids based on the alphabets passed.

Comment: Does JQL search not support getting an email for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API to get a user from his email address.

```
curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization:Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" http://yourjiraurl.com/rest/api/2/user/search?username=username
```

According to Jira documentation the username parameter will be matched against the username, name or email address.

To get your username password encoded you can use the `base64` command in linux.

```
echo -n username:password | base64
dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Replace this output in the first command since this call can not be made anonymously.

Comment: Thank you for your help . I have tried this and the REST API is working fine